# Are there any binary red supergiants?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, stars, observable-universe, binary-stars

I wonder if we ever have identified or observed a pair of binary stars (red supergiants).
And I also wonder what would happen if they exploded, (theoretically) as we havent observed it. Also, would currently existing binary stars have enough mass to later on burn out into a red giant, and then explode as a supernova, and would it affect us? It would be a violent explosion im sure.

Comment: crossposted to astronomy  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/50806/

Answer (score 0):

By "Universal" standards that could be possible, we don't have any candidates, but assuming two main sequence stars formed at around the same time and both having the same mass and lifespan. Then they would reach their giant phases at the same time, a could make a binary system type of which you are talking about. But this requires extremely specific conditions.